# Simplify the fraction so there are no negative exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Simplify the fraction so there are no negative exponents
>   $$\frac{x^{-9}+y^{-9}}{\frac{x^3+y^3}{y^{-2}}}=\frac AB$$

Tried everything with this problem but cannot get the answer in a quiz that doesn't reveal the right answer but only tells you you are wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

$$x^{-9}+y^{-9}=\frac{x^9+y^9}{x^9y^9}$$

$$x^9+y^9=(x^3+y^3)(x^6-x^3y^3+y^6)$$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $x^{-9}+y^{-9}=\frac{1}{x^9}+\frac{1}{y^9}=\frac{x^9y^9}{x^9+y^9}$.
Also, $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{y^{-2}}}=\frac{1}{y^2}$.